# Using Reflection to access Dtmf functionalties in Android

Tags: android, reflection, dtmf

everyone.
I'm trying to access the sendDtmf method in android.internal.telephony.CallManager using Reflection to send these tones to an IVR Voice.

The code is the following:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;


public class RefelectionFactory {

public boolean sendDtmf(char c, Context context) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    try{
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      //Class Phone = cl.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.Phone");

        ClassLoader classLoader = context.getClassLoader();
        final Class<?> classCallManager = classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[1];
      paramTypes[0]= Context.class;

      //Method get = Phone.getMethod("sendDtmf",  paramTypes);
      Method get = classCallManager.getMethod("sendDtmf",  paramTypes);
      get.setAccessible(true);

      //Parameters
      Object[] params= new Object[1];
      params[0]= context;

      get.invoke(null, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        Log.e("ERRORE", "sendDtmf", e);
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

When I'm compiling the code, in LogCat this Exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sendDtmf [class android.content.Context]
java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
it.digitalnatives.*****.ricarica.RefelectionFactory.sendDtmf(RefelectionFactory.java:39)
it.digitalnatives.*****.ricarica.MainRicarica$2.onClick(MainRicarica.java:541)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm stuck with this stuff and i've some requests.
1) Is this code correct?
2) The sendDtmf() method really exist in ClassManager class and if so can I access to that?

Any suggestion will be strong appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different set of parameter types, I can't remember `sendDtmf` ever taking a `Context` - the ICS and 2.3 versions all take a `char`, i.e. `CallManager#sendDtmf(char c)`

I'd recommend:

```
Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{char.class};
Method get = classCallManager.getMethod("sendDtmf",  paramTypes);
```

**Edit**: Now with an example.

```
class Dtmf {
    private static final String CALL_MANAGER = "com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager";
    private static final String SEND_DTMF = "sendDtmf";
    private static final String GET_INSTANCE = "getInstance";
    private Method mSendDtmfMethod;
    private Object mCallManager;
    public Dtmf() {
        try {
            Class<?> callManagerClass = Class.forName(CALL_MANAGER);
            // Obtain an instance of CallManager
            Method getInstanceMethod = callManagerClass.getMethod(GET_INSTANCE);
            mCallManager = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null);
            // Get sendDtmf(char)
            Class<?>[] sendDtmfParamTypes = new Class<?>[]{char.class};
            mSendDtmfMethod = callManagerClass.getMethod(SEND_DTMF, sendDtmfParamTypes);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }

    public boolean sendDtmf(char ch) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (mCallManager != null && mSendDtmfMethod != null) {
            try {
                Object res = mSendDtmfMethod.invoke(mCallManager, 
                        new Object[]{Character.valueOf(ch)});

                if (res instanceof Boolean) {
                    result = ((Boolean) res).booleanValue(); 
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Dunno what protections they've placed inside the call manager - or if you, as a user application, is even able to invoke this method successfully - but this example will at least let you try.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I think we made a step forward. Now i get another exception on Method m.invoke(Object receiver, Object...args).       `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager, but got java.lang.Class<com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager>.` Any clue? Thanks again.

Comment: Well, for starters you need to pass it a `Character` object instead of the context. You also need to pass it an instance of the class instead of `null` here: `get.invoke(null, params);`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't paste you the actual code which thrown that exception. Here it is: `String className = "com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager";
    
    
    try {
     Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
    
     
      //Class[] paramTypes= new Class[1];
      Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{char.class};
     Method m = myClass.getMethod("sendDtmf", paramTypes);
     m.setAccessible(true);
     m.invoke(myClass, '1');
    } `. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: it always return false .. ant clue ??